# Canvas is drawing a rotated image

Tags: javascript, canvas, camera, rotation, drawimage

I am attempting to use javascript to take a picture with my iphone and draw the image to the canvas. I use

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField">

 mobilePictureGet);
```

to use the camera. Once I choose a picture

```
document.getElementById("takePictureField").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        if(e.target.files.length == 1 && e.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }          
      }
```

this fires, and the image appears how I want it in the  tag. (so far so good), However, I draw it to the canvas when img tag has loaded:

```
img.onload = function() {
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width,img.height);
      }
```

and it appears rotated -90 degrees. I have tried

```
var x = width / 2;
var y = height / 2;
var angleInRadians = Math.PI / 2;

ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, img.width, img.height);
ctx.rotate(-angleInRadians);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
```

but I can't get it to fit.

Does anyone know why the canvas would draw the image rotated? Any help to get the picture drawn correctly on the canvas is much appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably depends on how you hold your phone. That (orientation) information is stored in the exif data of the image and you have to rotate it accordingly.
One library that can help you with this is [JavaScript Load Image](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/)

Comment: That was it! The exif data! Thank you so much. I'm able to rotate the rotate the image with ease using JavaScript Load Image.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to take a picture with javascript, but I do some ios mobile development.

The reason the picture comes out sideways at all, is because apple has deemed that holding your phone with the home button facing right is the only acceptable way to take a picture.  This is also known as it's 'up' state.

More information on why your iPhone takes pictures sideways can be found here:  http://rotatemailer.com/sideways-pictures.html

In ios it's very easy to rotate it, so in javascript i'm not too sure how to properly do that.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I tried taking the pic with the home button to the right, and it oriented correctly, but the scaling was off due to squeezing it into the canvas sideways. Ended up solving this with the help of JavaScript Load Image